# String subset from cookie variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation

I have a string in ruby (stored a cookie variable), it consist latitude and longitude separate by | character.Like "47.497912|19.040235"  How can i separate two different float variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple:

```
=> "47.497912|19.040235".split('|').map(&:to_f)
=> # [47.497912,  19.040235]
```

update:

i find more elegant solution:

```
=> latitude, _, longitude = "47.497912|19.040235".partition('|').map(&:to_f)
=> latitude
 # 47.497912
=> longitude
 # 19.040235
```